# How to copy the one column to other column in same table using Node.js and Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table called *Events*, which has 3 column ID, totalTask and completed.
I want to refresh the data of *completed* column by updating the *completed* column same as a *totalTask* column

Current table:

[image]

We know that it is easy as a Mysql command:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = column2
```

However, I had tried using sequelize npm package, I was confused with Syntax.

What I had tried (I know it is completely dumb)?

```
const updateResults = await Events.update({completed:{totalTask}}).
```

Expected output:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: add where condition to identify the row

Comment: @RahulKumar, yes I had written but, Sequelize will not know that.
user_limits.update({Monthly_Available}, {where: {Monthly}})

Comment: there should be some foreign key which links both table using id so that you can find out the matching ID

Comment: @RahulKumar, please understand the question, am talking about within the table.there is no 2 tables

Comment: it's not possible then without where clause otherwise it'll update all records.

Comment: UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = column2 WHERE ID = 1;